# How can I output Handbrake output to both the screen and to a file?

Tags: powershell, exe, output-redirect

So I've been using Handbrake command line to encode my video collection to store on my NAS so I can use it on my HTPC. I was looking for a way to output both to the screen so I can watch it's output as it's encoding, but also to a file so I can go back and look at a particular encoding session.

My solution for this was to use one Powershell window to run the encoding and output to a file, then another Powershell window to read the log file and display it on screen. This works, but I want to improve it, as it's not perfect. Because the read file script reads at a set interval, it misses lines. Also if I reduce the interval, it has an effect on system performance, making the encoding run a bit slower. Is there a way I can redirect the output of the first window to both a file and to the screen?

The first powershell script (the one that starts the encoding) called "Convert1.ps1" (run from the handbrake install directory):

```
net time \\ODIN |find "Current time"
./HandbrakeCLI.exe -i "<input file>" -o "<output file>" <handbrake parameters>
```

The second powershell script to output to a file, called "Start_Convert.ps1":

```
d:\Conversions\Convert.ps1 2>&1 | out-file d:\Conversions\Completed\Movies\9.29.2010.log
```

The third powershell script to read from that log file, called "Watch_Output.ps1":

```
while (1)
{
(Get-Content d:\Conversions\Completed\Movies\9.29.2010.log)[-1]
Start-sleep 5
}
```

I'd like, ideally, to get this all down to one powershell window running a single script to start the encoding, output to a file, and display it on screen.

Edit (Adding Solution):
2 different ways to do it, I'm going with the latter since it is simpler.

Way #1 - Start-Job
Resulting script to start my conversions:

```
Start-Job -Name VideoConvert -ScriptBlock { d:\Conversions\Convert.ps1 2>&1 | out-file d:\Conversions\Movies\Movie.log }
Get-FileTail -Wait Encoding Unicode -Path D:\Conversions\Completed\Movies\Movie.log
```

Way #2 - Tee-Object
Resulting script to start my conversions:

```
d:\Conversions\Convert.ps1 2>&1 |Tee-Object -File D:\Conversions\Completed\Movies\Movie.log
```

Thanks again all. This works just like I wanted it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use Tee-Object for this:

```
./HandbrakeCLI.exe -i infile -o outfile ... 2>&1 | Tee-Object -File movie.log
```

Added in the `2>&1` to capture errors to the log as well as the screen.

Comment: I tried that initially, but the problem with that is, I am doing these commands in batches, and in those batches I do stuff like record the date and time the covnersion started and stopped as well as create directories and other various file tasks. I want to capture everything from the entire batch of conversions (usually like 10-20 video conversions at a time) so that I can diagnose any problems that occured if I get errors somewhere along the line. So I need a single log file for an entire batch and Goyuix's solution worked though I used fenster's suggestion for a tail function.

Comment: Actually wait...that does work better...though I changed it to work on the convert.ps1 file instead.

Comment: Ahhh yes... Tee-Object. Great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is to grab the tail.exe binary from the [UnxUtils package](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and run it as follows:

```
tail -f D:\Conversions\Completed\Movies\9.29.1010.log
```

Unfortunately you will need to do that in a second command prompt (or PowerShell) window, but it will "**f**ollow" that file and display the lines from the log as they are added.

If you really want to keep that in a single window, you will need PowerShell v2 and you can start the encoding as a job (allowing it to run in the background) and then follow that command with a call to tail for displaying the results:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { ./HandbrakeCLI.exe -i "in" -o "out" "params" > log.txt }
tail -f log.txt
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks, I'll give it a try. I'll be back if I can get it to work correctly.

Comment: Ok, only one problem, the output that tail produces is double spaced.

Comment: What about the tail function in Powershell Community Extensions - http://pscx.codeplex.com/?

Comment: Ah, thank you fenster, that worked. Had to specify the encoding as Unicode to get it to work, but it works perfectly.